# Converting non padded string to Date (in a given format) in python

Tags: python, string, date

I'm trying to convert non padded string to date in python and getting following error:

```
e_dataframe['Modified_Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(e_dataframe['Modified_Date'], format='%d/%m/%y %I:%M %p')

ValueError: time data '1/08/2018 4:41 PM' does not match format '%d/%m/%y %I:%M %p' (match)
```

The format is similar still getting an error.

Comment: `%y` only matches a **two digit year**, not a 4 digit year

Comment: @MartijnPieters : Thanks, Man! It worked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`%y` matches a year with two digits, omitting the century. Your input has a 4 digit year, so you need to use `%Y`:

```
'%d/%m/%Y %I:%M %p'
```

When in doubt, use `datetime.strptime()` with a *substring* of your input so you can see what parts work and what parts fail:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('1', '%d')
datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('1/08', '%d/%m')
datetime.datetime(1900, 8, 1, 0, 0)
>>> datetime.datetime.strptime('1/08/2018', '%d/%m/%y')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 577, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
  File "/Users/mj/Development/Library/buildout.python/parts/opt/lib/python3.7/_strptime.py", line 362, in _strptime
    data_string[found.end():])
ValueError: unconverted data remains: 18
```

The error indicates that `%y` only processed the `20` part of the year, telling us that it was not the correct placeholder for the `2018` input.